# Feed answer to interactive command line in C#

Tags: c#

I need to write a C# program that will call an external command (i.e. plink.exe) and pass the "yes" answer to it.

For example, in a command prompt, I would do this:

`echo yes | plink.exe <plink arguments here>`

Is there a way I can do this with C# without having to invoke "cmd /c" to call the whole thing? This program will need to be called from another system as part of an automation, and I would like to avoid having to spawn too many nested shells (currently using UseShellExecute = false in StartInfo to avoid it).

Comment: So you know about `Process` and dont want to use it?

Comment: No I know about it just enough to launch a program with it, but I don't know how to pass input to the process I'm starting without having to rely on pipes in a shell "i.e. call the command with cmd.exe /c echo yes | plink.exe". I would like to know if it's possible to just call the program (plink) directly and still pass an input to it. Is that clearer?

Comment: You need to redirect STDIN on the new process. There's an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx)

Comment: Ok, so I basically have to redirect stdin, and then start the process and write to its stdin with a separate call. I'll try it, thanks! The example is a bit more complex than what I need (prompts for user to input lines) but I think I can manage it. If you create an answer for this I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't really have time to write up a working example, but feel free to post your own answer once you figure it out - I'll upvote it :)